# Reducing the number of tuples in a list based on a threshold

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

i have a list that contains number of tuples.

`POIs = [(3,2),(6,2),(6,5),(10,1),(12,-2),(5,7)]`

the tuples inside of `POIs` are 2D-coordinates of detected objects. What i'm trying to do is to check the eucludian distance between these objects so that if the distance between each two objects is smaller than `3`, then the two objects are considered as one and the new coordinate would be the average distance between them.

Conceptionally,this looks like a clustering problem and requires to examine the distance of **every object with the other** and calculate the distance like

```
# example, hier only the first two points are considered
d = np.sqrt(np.abs(POIs[0][0]-POIs[1][0]) + np.abs(POIs[0][1]-POIs[1][1]))

 if (d<3):
   POIs[0] = (POIs[0][0]+POIs[1][0]/2 , POIs[0][1]+POIs[1][1]/2)
```

So, my question is if this could be computationally optimized as this becomes worse when the list includes a large number of tuples/objects

Comment: Use the square of the distances for faster calculation. Use a good library (numpy is a start) that is optimised for this kind of problem: don't reinvent the wheel, unless as an exercise.

Comment: @00 thanks for the comment. I know self-search and learn is always a good thing. However, i would be grateful, if you could express it through an example on the POIs given above ^ ^

Comment: You could also set d<9 and leave out the np.sqrt()

Comment: Is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html practical for you?

Comment: You could also do a lot of if checks that find d=3 points for each tuple, then excludes the points larger. This would be much faster for larger arrays but slower for smaller ones probably. However, it is a lot more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using SciPy's [`fclusterdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata

max_dist = 3
points = [(3, 2), (6, 2), (6, 5), (10, 1), (12, -2), (5, 7)]

clusters = fclusterdata(points, t=max_dist, criterion='distance')
clustered_points = (pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['x', 'y'], index=clusters)
                      .rename_axis(index='cluster'))
cluster_centroids = (clustered_points.groupby(clusters).mean()
                                     .rename_axis(index='cluster'))
```

Here is your desired result:

```
>>> clustered_points
          x  y
cluster       
1         3  2
1         6  2
1         6  5
2        10  1
3        12 -2
1         5  7
>>> cluster_centroids
          x  y
cluster       
1         5  4
2        10  1
3        12 -2
```

Comment: Awsome, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Despite this is irrelevant to the question. Do you know how to reshape the `cluster_centroids` to a list of tuples like `cluster_centroids=[(5, 4), (10, 1), (12, -2)]`, since i can't get index the x and y

Comment: @Zang322 `list(map(tuple, cluster_centroids.values))`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the scipy package. Concretely, your issue can be solved with

`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(POIs)`

By default, this command will use the traditional Euclidean distance. In your case, for 6 elements il will create an array of 15 elements containing the distances between points.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, how can i use the 15 element matrix to extract the new object coordinates?.

Comment: The first thing is to understand why 15 is the number of distances computed. In case that is clear, you should be able to know which pair correspond to each distance. You can think in terms of a triangular matrix.

Comment: Beautiful answer.